# What is the difference between gradlew build and gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I want to build apk from command line with the help of gradle. Which command should I use to build apks for only release flavours?

Answer (score 27):

Debug

```
./gradlew
```

Release

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

your gradle file should contains:

```
android {
   [...]
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("../keystore.jks")
            storePassword "pwd"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "pwd"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


   [...]
}
```

Answer (score 18):

You can run these commands:

```
assemble - Assembles all variants of all applications and secondary packages.
build - Assembles and tests this project.
```

If you want a specific flavor or buildtype use:

```
assembleDebug - Assembles all Debug builds.
assembleRelease - Assembles all Release builds.
```

In your case use:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriele, assembleRelease builds all release builds. Do we need unaligned builds as well for continous integration ?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to upload the APK file to your firebase app distribtion, use the below command:

```
# generates debug signed APK
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

It will generate an APK file, but it couldn't be released to Play Store, as it signed with your debug signature. GPC won't allow it to be uploaded.

If you want to upload the APK or AAB file to Google Play Console, use one of the commands below:

```
# generates release signed APK
./gradlew assembleRelease
# generates release signed AAB
./gradlew bundleRelease
```